# How to account for milliseconds using _DateDiff()?

Tags: autoit, datediff

I am trying to calculate elapsed time (between date-values from two cells in Excel) using AutoIt:

```
_DateDiff($sType, $sStartDate, $sEndDate)
```

My problem is `_DateDiff()` does not take milliseconds into account.
It's giving me the elapsed time in seconds but I want it in seconds + milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

1. You could extend the function yourself.
2. You could calculate your values `* 1000` and after the function `/ 1000`.

   ```
   ; #FUNCTION# ====================================================================================================================
   ; Author ........: Jos van der Zande
   ; Modified.......:
   ; ===============================================================================================================================
   Func _DateDiff($sType, $sStartDate, $sEndDate)
       ; Verify that $sType is Valid
       $sType = StringLeft($sType, 1)
       If StringInStr("d,m,y,w,h,n,s", $sType) = 0 Or $sType = "" Then
           Return SetError(1, 0, 0)
       EndIf
       ; Verify If StartDate is valid
       If Not _DateIsValid($sStartDate) Then
           Return SetError(2, 0, 0)
       EndIf
       ; Verify If EndDate is valid
       If Not _DateIsValid($sEndDate) Then
           Return SetError(3, 0, 0)
       EndIf
       Local $asStartDatePart[4], $asStartTimePart[4], $asEndDatePart[4], $asEndTimePart[4]
       ; split the StartDate and Time into arrays
       _DateTimeSplit($sStartDate, $asStartDatePart, $asStartTimePart)
       ; split the End  Date and time into arrays
       _DateTimeSplit($sEndDate, $asEndDatePart, $asEndTimePart)
       ; ====================================================
       ; Get the differens in days between the 2 dates
       Local $aDaysDiff = _DateToDayValue($asEndDatePart[1], $asEndDatePart[2], $asEndDatePart[3]) - _DateToDayValue($asStartDatePart[1], $asStartDatePart[2], $asStartDatePart[3])
       ; ====================================================
       Local $iTimeDiff, $iYearDiff, $iStartTimeInSecs, $iEndTimeInSecs
       ; Get the differens in Seconds between the 2 times when specified
       If $asStartTimePart[0] > 1 And $asEndTimePart[0] > 1 Then
           $iStartTimeInSecs = $asStartTimePart[1] * 3600 + $asStartTimePart[2] * 60 + $asStartTimePart[3]
           $iEndTimeInSecs = $asEndTimePart[1] * 3600 + $asEndTimePart[2] * 60 + $asEndTimePart[3]
           $iTimeDiff = $iEndTimeInSecs - $iStartTimeInSecs
           If $iTimeDiff < 0 Then
               $aDaysDiff = $aDaysDiff - 1
               $iTimeDiff = $iTimeDiff + 24 * 60 * 60
           EndIf
       Else
           $iTimeDiff = 0
       EndIf
       Select
           Case $sType = "d"
               Return $aDaysDiff
           Case $sType = "m"
               $iYearDiff = $asEndDatePart[1] - $asStartDatePart[1]
               Local $iMonthDiff = $asEndDatePart[2] - $asStartDatePart[2] + $iYearDiff * 12
               If $asEndDatePart[3] < $asStartDatePart[3] Then $iMonthDiff = $iMonthDiff - 1
               $iStartTimeInSecs = $asStartTimePart[1] * 3600 + $asStartTimePart[2] * 60 + $asStartTimePart[3]
               $iEndTimeInSecs = $asEndTimePart[1] * 3600 + $asEndTimePart[2] * 60 + $asEndTimePart[3]
               $iTimeDiff = $iEndTimeInSecs - $iStartTimeInSecs
               If $asEndDatePart[3] = $asStartDatePart[3] And $iTimeDiff < 0 Then $iMonthDiff = $iMonthDiff - 1
               Return $iMonthDiff
           Case $sType = "y"
               $iYearDiff = $asEndDatePart[1] - $asStartDatePart[1]
               If $asEndDatePart[2] < $asStartDatePart[2] Then $iYearDiff = $iYearDiff - 1
               If $asEndDatePart[2] = $asStartDatePart[2] And $asEndDatePart[3] < $asStartDatePart[3] Then $iYearDiff = $iYearDiff - 1
               $iStartTimeInSecs = $asStartTimePart[1] * 3600 + $asStartTimePart[2] * 60 + $asStartTimePart[3]
               $iEndTimeInSecs = $asEndTimePart[1] * 3600 + $asEndTimePart[2] * 60 + $asEndTimePart[3]
               $iTimeDiff = $iEndTimeInSecs - $iStartTimeInSecs
               If $asEndDatePart[2] = $asStartDatePart[2] And $asEndDatePart[3] = $asStartDatePart[3] And $iTimeDiff < 0 Then $iYearDiff = $iYearDiff - 1
               Return $iYearDiff
           Case $sType = "w"
               Return Int($aDaysDiff / 7)
           Case $sType = "h"
               Return $aDaysDiff * 24 + Int($iTimeDiff / 3600)
           Case $sType = "n"
               Return $aDaysDiff * 24 * 60 + Int($iTimeDiff / 60)
           Case $sType = "s"
               Return $aDaysDiff * 24 * 60 * 60 + $iTimeDiff
       EndSelect
   EndFunc   ;==>_DateDiff
   ```